# cut and paste documents between sharepoint portals

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to cut and paste documents/files between share point portals in windows explorer view. Its not allowing me to do it. Is it a  bug or any setting I can get it to work? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A guess: to avoid dataloss (versions etc.) SharePoint might not offer that level of integration with Windows Explorer.

Cut and paste is lossy. Prefer to move.

[How can you move a document with its version history to a new library?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/1278/11050)

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your System and Internet Explorer (Test it again with another system)
2. do not test it in the server (that you install SharePoint)
3. Change your Trusted location Setting in Internet Explorer
4. test it only with internet explorer
5. ensure that your client joined to domain
6. ensure that user that login in windows same as login with IE
7. there are two ways to open :

   - with option that you open by SharePoint
   - by replaacing "\\" with "http://" and replace "\" with "/" : for example if `http://servername/sitename/DocLib1`  you are type : \\servername\sitename\DocLib1